# Probability distribution of a Binomial random variable given a dependent Poisson random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Before I start, I'm sorry if the title isn't appropriate for the question.

Could anyone help me with this problem, please?

Problem: Suppose that the number of phone calls that arrive on your cell phone during
the day has a Poisson distribution with parameter λ > 0. With probability p ∈ (0, 1) any one of these calls, independently, can be unwelcome. What is the Probability Distribution of the number of unwanted connections during a day?

My solution (so far):

X = number of calls I receive on a day

Y = number of unwanted calls I receive on a day

The only solution that came to mind was tring to use Bayes:

$P[Y=y/X=x] = \frac{P[X=x/Y=y] P[Y=y]}{P[X=x]}$

$P[X=x] = \frac{e^{-λ} λ^x}{x!}$

$P[Y=y/X=x] = $ $x\choose y$ $p^y (1-p)^{x-y}$

But now I see that I can't calculate $P[X=x/Y=y]$ nor $P[Y=y]$, since $P[Y=y]$ depends on X and $P[X=x/Y=y]$ looks like is not a Poisson anymore, since it won't start on zero. Did I choose the right way and I just don't know how to continue or going with Bayes was the wrong idea?

P.S: I'm on my first semester of probability

Comment: Hint: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution) and then use the characteristic function to find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are as you have defined them, then what you actually want to determine is the unconditional (also called "marginal") distribution of $Y$; that is to say, independent of $X$, how many unwanted calls are received?

Therefore, the appropriate theorem to apply is the law of total probability:

$$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] \Pr[X = x], \tag{1}$$ where the conditional random variable $Y \mid X$ is binomial with parameters $n = X$ and $p$.  This is because, given that $X$ calls are received in a day, the number of these calls that are unwanted is a binomial random variable, since the outcome of each call is essentially a Bernoulli trial with probability $p$ of being unwanted.  Hence $$\Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] = \binom{x}{y} p^y (1-p)^{x-y}, \quad y \in \{0, 1, \ldots, x\}. \tag{2}$$

Therefore, $(1)$ gives
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \binom{x}{y} p^y (1-p)^{x-y} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}. \tag{3}$$
But since it is impossible to receive more unwanted calls than total calls (i.e., we must have $Y \ge X$), the sum $(3)$ should be written
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{x=y}^\infty \binom{x}{y} p^y (1-p)^{x-y} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}. \tag{4}$$
I leave the evaluation of this sum to you as an exercise.